# How do I pass an array or list of values to Java via system properties - and how do I access it?

Tags: java, arrays, list, environment-variables

Is there a way to pass a list of values into Java, using only one system property?

I'm thinking of something along the lines `-DMY_LIST=val1,val2,val3` or `-DMY_LIST={val1, val2}`

Any ideas?

How would I access that in Java?

Update: I initially asked for environment variables, but actually meant system properties. Similar principle, but quite different... I changed title and text accordingly now. Thanks, @serge-ballesta

Comment: Lots of ideas, what have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  I would take a the environment variable which is a String and `split(",")` it.

Comment: I think my actual reason for this question was more along the lines of "what's the proper way to do it?" and "what syntax do I have to use, i.e. curly braces or not?" - haven't tried anything yet to be honest, as I wanted to hear what others would do and how it would be done "the proper way". I know I'd use curly braces to pass lists into annotations, but wasn't sure what it would look like for a command line argument like -D...

Comment: IMHO it is very unusual to pass information via environment variables and even less common to pass lists of values this way.  Normally you would have a configuration file e.g. Properties, JSon, or Yaml, and you would set it in there.

Comment: Beware : -DMY_LIST=val1,val2,val3 (or --DMY_LIST="val1,val2,val3" which is the same) do not set environment variables but system properties. See my edit below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Oracle Javase tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html)
*On the Java platform, an application uses System.getenv to retrieve environment variable values. Without an argument, getenv returns a read-only instance of java.util.Map, where the map keys are the environment variable names, and the map values are the environment variable values.*

So if you have an environment variable `MY_LIST=val1,val2,val3`, you can use it as simple as

```
String strlist = System.getenv().get("MY_LIST");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strlist.split(","));
```

Edit: fixed call of getenv (forgot parentheses - thanks to Christian)

I must precise that my anwer concerns **environment variable** which is the title of the post. But `java -D MY_LIST=a,b,c ...` sets **system properties** and it in **not** the same.
To access system properties set by `-D` option, I should write instead :

```
String strlist = System.getProperty("MY_LIST");
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(strlist.split(","));
```

Comment: @Christian Thanks for helping me to improve my answer. I tried it in Java 7 and if I put curly braces ... I get them in `strlist` and simply have to skip them.

Comment: Ha, I knew I was mixing stuff up... ;) Thank you!